# Average function in PivotTable for specific rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, pivot-table

I copied this from a PivotTable:

```
Country Airport Shoes Jackets   ShoesAverage   JacketsAverage 
Albania TIA      35    270
                 35    270
                 35    270
                 35    300
                 35    210
                 35    210
                 35    210
 Algeria ALG     305   200
                 125   480
                 125   480
                  65   360
                 125   480
                  65   360
```

I am looking for a smart way of dealing with average by country. Let's say I have supplied 35 Shoes per week from `TIA` (which is an airport) and want the average of `TIA` per week under `ShoesAverage` and similarly for `JacketsAverage` and the option to apply the same for countries without copying the formula multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

A 'stab in the dark' since the requirement does not seem to me to be defined clearly:

[image: SO 19185149 example]